JPA Criteria Query - is it possible to add an inner join subquery that has multiple fields
I have the query below and would like to translate it into a Criteria query. However, most of the examples I see online use only a single selected field in the subquery. Is it possible to have multiple selected subquery fields?
select * from quiz q inner join (
  select max_date(createddate), completeName
  from quiz
  group by completeName
) latest_quiz on latest_quiz.max_date = q.createddate and latest_quiz.completeName=q.completeName

